# android dialogFragment "sometimes" not showing webview

Tags: android, android-webview, android-dialogfragment

I have a DialogFragment with a WebView inside it. If the webview does not load the page fast enough, the DialogFragment will shrink completely and not show the webview. Otherwise, if the loading was fast, the WebView is shown.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the solution by myself. If you use LinearLayout as the root view for your DialogFragment this will happen, changing it to FrameLayout resolved the problem. I do not understand why, but it works.

Comment: In my case the root view was a FrameLayout and I switched it to RelativeLayout and it magically worked... very strange. It now doesn' correctly size to its content meaning it matches_parent, but thats ok for me.

Answer (score 3):

I tried in two devices.

In first device Nexus 6 worked like say David "I found the solution by myself. If you use LinearLayout as the root view for your DialogFragment this will happen, changing it to FrameLayout resolved the problem. I do not understand why, but it works". But i tried in second device (Galaxy Prime) and surprise, not worked. After tried make setVisible GONE WebView in my WebViewClient inside callback `onPageStarted()` and after setVisible VISIBLE inside callback `onPageFinished()` and worked for my.

```html
public class MyWebClient extends WebViewClient { 

    private static final String LOG_CAT = "NetPayWebClient";

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        Log.e(LOG_CAT, "onPageStarted(): " + url);
        view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        Log.e(LOG_CAT, "onPageFinished(): " + url);
        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I used custom WebView like `ExpandableHeightWebView` for dynamic height.

```
@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
{
    if (isExpanded())
    {

        int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(MEASURED_SIZE_MASK,
                MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
        params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
    }
    else
    {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```

I'm calling `setExpanded(true);` after `myWebView.loadData(data,null);`
This problem solved when I delete `setExpanded(true);` line.

Answer (score -1):

If you may loading the web view through AsyncTaks the Dialog fragment does not show because AsyncTasks cannot change layout who is in the main thread.
Take a look at it.